# using variable in mongo javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

When running checkpoints.js script below

```
$ mongo -u "admin" -p "xxx" monitor checkpoints.js
```

it doesn't look like variable 'i' can be used inside db statement ?

```
for (var i=1; i<8; i++) {
        print(i)
        print(db.checkpoints.find({day: i}).count())
}
```

Because it prints zeros for me

```
1
0
2
0
3
0
4
0
5
0
6
0
7
0
```

Comment: And if you do `db.checkpoints.find({day: 3}).count()` it **does** return a result ?

Comment: only after I did i.toString(), sorry...

Comment: That's what I thought, I was just about to suggest `.find({day: i.toString()})` but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

The zero that is printing is the count of your query, not the variable `i`.

#### Update

I misunderstood your question, the variable can be used, just check that your query returns non-empty result by running it manually:

```
db.checkpoints.find({day: 1}).count()
```